# Как в списке записей вывести изображение в OctoberCMS?

Tags: october

Возможно ли в списке статей, в блоге от Rainlab, вывести изображение?

Пробовал вырвать кусок из одиночной статьи так:

```
{% set image = __SELF__.post.featured_images.first %} 
<img src="{{ image.path }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
```

и так:

```
{% for image in post.featured_images %}
    <a href="{{ post.url }}"><img data-src="{{ image.filename }}" src="{{ image.path }}" alt="{{ image.description }}"></a>
    {% endfor %}
```

но ничего не вышло.

Как можно это сделать и возможно ли вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так
Заменил

```
{{ image.path }}
```

на

```
 {{ post.featured_images[0]['path'] }}
```